# Let $E$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then is it also true that $E$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ equipped with the $||\cdot||_1$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Since $E$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ I know $\forall\vec{x}\in{E}$,  then $\exists{r}$>$0$ such that $B_r{(\vec{x})}\subset{E}$.

I was figuring I need to find some other $s$< $r$ such that $\forall \vec{y}\in B_r{(\vec{x})}$, then $B_{s}(\vec{y})\subset B_r(\vec{x})$ when using the $||\cdot||_1$. This would show that each $B_r{(\vec{x})}$ is an open set when using the 1 norm. Thus implying that the original set $E$ is also open under the same 1 norm since the original ball is arbitrary.

This is just my initial thinking, but I have not been able to go anywhere with this. Something I was also trying to play around with was the following, if we denote:

$$\vec{x}=(x_1, x_2, ..., x_d)$$
$$\vec{y}=(y_1, y_2, ..., y_d)$$
Then, for i=1, 2, 3, ..., d.

$$|x_i-y_i|<|x_i-y_i|^2\text{  whenever } 1<|x_i-y_i|$$
$$|x_i-y_i|\geq|x_i-y_i|^2\text{  whenever } 1\geq|x_i-y_i|$$

However, I am at a wall as to what I should do next or if this is the correct line of logic.

Comment: I suggest that you think abput the shape of the balls. Consider $d=2$ or $d=3$ to visualise it.

Comment: This doesn't relate to your approach, but the answer is yes - all norms on finite dimensional vector spaces are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

For all $\vec{x} \in \Bbb R^n$ we have that $\|x\|_2 \le \|x\|_1$: this follows from the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^2 a_i^2 \le (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)^2$ for all $a_1,\ldots,a_n \ge 0$ in $\Bbb R$, and taking square roots.

So if $E$ is open under $\|\cdot\|_2$, the usual norm and $\vec{x} \in O$ we have
$r>0$ such that $B_2(\vec{x}, r) \subseteq E$, where $B_2$ denotes the open ball
under the usual norm.

The inequality gives (if $B_1$ denotes the ball under the $\|\cdot\|_1$-norm (metric)) that $B_1(\vec{x},r) \subseteq B_2(\vec{x},r)$ and so the same $r$ can be used for $x$ and $E$ under the $\|\cdot\|_1$-norm and $E$ is open under that norm too.

You can also find an inequality the other way around to see that norm 1 open sets are norm-2 open as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the fact that $\|x\| \leq \|x\|_1$ where $\|x\|$ is the usual norm.